# In Dungeon Fighter, what is the priority between death and activating an ability?

Tags: untagged

I've got this question because I cannot find it in the rule book:

I roll the dice, I miss (so the monster attacks me), I die because of the miss, but the dice shows the "eye" (so for example I activate an ability that works even when the dice misses). In this case, the ability is activated before I die or I die before activating the ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick disclaimer, I've not played the game or even heard of it until I read the question.   However, I've watched a tutorial video and found the [rules online here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191030090958/http://www.horrible-games.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Dungeonfighter_Rules_ENG_v5.pdf)  to try and find the answer for you.

Look at the rules on page 9 for 'No Damage'  it says :-

> No damage: If activated, the hero takes no damage if he misses the target board.

This might infer that you get to activate this ability before taking damage.  However unhelpfully back on page 7 the rules say this :-

> Hint: The damage dealt while becoming defeated by a
> monster is not avoidable. No special powers can prevent that
> damage.

It would be really helpful to have that 'hint' on a page with all the abilities but it does seem to make it explicit that if a monster defeats you then you do not get to activate a special power, including those that are activated when a character misses.

Comment: Thank you for your effort in reading rules for a game that you don't have! In BoardGameGeek forum I received the right answer: the ability activates before dying when there is a "miss" with the dice. It is not well explained in the italian rulebook, that's why I asked. Thank you again!